# Determining DKIM Selector and Key Values for my domain, hosted on 1&1

Tags: dns, 1and1, dkim

I have a client that is with 1&1 (yeah, I know). He's asked me to set up SPF and DKIM records for his domain.

I am **not** experienced with email configuration (I'm just a lowly web developer) but I managed to figure out the correct settings for the SPF record (using TXT type) but I just cannot figure out what to do about the DKIM. I know it needs the type to be TXT but I have no idea what the prefix selector should be and no idea what the value should be either. In the examples I've found the value is a long string of characters...and thats about the extent of my knowledge.

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

**EDIT 1: More Info**
Turns out 1&1 only support DKIM on dedicated hosting accounts, not shared hosting as my client is on. Oh well.